# Java: Prime Number Program Not Working

Tags: java

Why does the int `j` only get the value 2? Doesn't `(int)realNum` mean that it must be a natural number?

```
Scanner basicNum = new Scanner(System. in );
String insertNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert a number\n");

int realNum = Integer.parseInt(insertNum);
int j = realNum = 1;

if (realNum < 10000) {
    while ((realNum / j == (int) realNum)) {
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println(j);
    if (j > 2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is not a prime!!");
    }

    if (j < 2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is a prime!");
    }
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Too large number!");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: `int j = realNum = 1;` is the same as  `realNum = 1;` `int j = realNum ;` hence `int j =1;`

Comment: And `while (( realNum / j == (int)realNum)) { j++;} ` will execute once,  when j=2 it exits while loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8, you can easily do it like this:

```
boolean isPrime(final int n) {
    return IntStream.range(2, n / 2+1).noneMatch(i -> n % i == 0);
}
```

On earlier versions, this one should do the same work,

```
    String insertNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert a number\n");
    int realNum = Integer.parseInt(insertNum);
    boolean prime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= realNum / 2; i++) {
         if (realNum % i == 0) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is not a prime!!");
              prime = false;
              break;
         }
    }
    if (prime) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is a prime!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`int j = realNum = 1;` sets `j` **and** `realNum` to 1.

So  `realNum / j == (int)realNum` is true until `j` is greater than 1. Hence your output.

The `(int)` prefix on `(int)realNum` is superfluous since `realNum` is already an `int` type.

Also `realNum / j` will be evaluated in integer arithmetic: any remainder is truncated.

Comment: Use your debugger. You might want to study the algorithm on paper first. Hint: primality test is normally done using modulus.